# search and replace of users hash from old server to the new one

Tags: awk, sed, password, replace

quite often I have to set the same password on new servers as it is on the old one, I can do it manually simple paste hash from the shadow, but I'd like to learn to do it automatically.

```
old machine A
new machine B
```

on new machine B exists users from A but also additional users which do not exist on A ( so shadow is not sorted, we can skip them of course )

is there a way via sed/awk to:

take hash from machine A , and replace exists users on new machine B where pwd is not set. (xxx:!:xxxx)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS=":" }
{
  if (NR==FNR) {
    pwd[$1]=$2
  } else {
    if ($2 ~ /^!/ && $1 in pwd) $2=pwd[$1]
    print
  }
}' shadowA shadowB
```

When the first file `shadowA` is processed (`NR==FNR`), save the password hash in array `pwd` with the username as index.

When the second file `shadowB` is processed (`else`) and the second field starts with a `!` (could be `!` or `!!`) and the username is present in the password array (`$1 in pwd`), then update the value of the second field. 
After that print the current line of `shadowB`.